# Pass options to Vitamio media

Tags: ios, objective-c, vitamio

The Vitamio for iOS has API

```
- (void)setOptionsWithKeys:(NSArray *)keys withValues:(NSArray *)values;
```

So anyone can tell me what are the keys and values here?
Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

Answer (score 0):

Basically reading the syntax I can say something like this:

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"name", @"age", @"phone"];
NSArray *values = @[@"John Smith", @"42", @"0123456789"];

[className setOptionWithKeys:keys withValues:values];
```

Comment: I wont say this is the perfect solution for you, but please explain your question a bit more for further help.

Comment: Thanks, but I did know keys and values are array objects, the problem here is what exactly are they, i mean the string in array

Comment: Which library of Vitamio are you using, yixia ?

Comment: Seems like I wont be able to help you on this. Please update your question with information you have provided in this comment section for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: pls give suggestin if possibe  on this question  i am facing isue since one week http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655245/unable-to-play-rtmp-live-video-stream-in-ios