# Unable to Play RTMP live video stream in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, rtmp, vitamio

I have downloaded sample code using this link:

https://github.com/yixia/Vitamio-iOS

I tried to play RTMP video streaming, but it does no play it gives the error:

> `NAL 1RRE &&&& VMediaPlayer Error: (null)`

I used this key:

```
keys[0] = @"-rtmp_live";
vals[0] = @"-1";
[mMPayer setOptionsWithKeys:keys withValues:vals];
```

Video does not play.

Does somebody have an idea why?

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: yes you must encode url using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding